# Where to put to_xls and from_xls in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, organization, export-to-excel, xls

So I have a model that I need to be able to serialize to/read from an Excel(XLS) document. I am a bit of a loss as to where this code actually belongs. My initial thought is that the to_xls is a view, but after poking around and seeing things like `(to|from)_xml` and `(to|from)_json` in ActiveRecord, I was wondering if maybe this stuff belonged in the model. Alternatively, does it belong in just a whole separate container somewhere?

For what it's worth, users will be downloading models from the site, modifying them in excel, then posting them.

Answer (score 0):

`to_xls` should *definitely* be a view. I'd try a `/app/views/foos/show.xls.erb`, but if you don't like ERB for XLS views, try the [RbTemplateHandler](http://gist.github.com/gists/193705) to do rendering in pure Ruby.

`from_xls` is a different beast altogether. It certainly doesn't belong in a controller. It logically belongs in the model, but I'd extract it to a mixin. If you're only pulling in XLS for one model, then the following setup should suffice:

```
# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo
  extend XLS2Foo
  ...
end

# lib/foo_from_xls
module XLS2Foo
  def to_foo(xls)
    ...
  end
end
```

If you need to do it for a bunch of models, you might try a parser-generator DSL in you `lib` directory and declare yourself parsers for each model in the model classes.

Comment: Realized that I need to do the same thing for a couple models, basically serializing to a tree-table. The main issue is whether I declare it as a model mix-in, or as something that acts on models that are a certain structure.

Answer (score 0):

to/from_xls are not supported by Rails. There is a plugin, but I haven't used it [to_xls plugin for Rails](http://arydjmal.com/2009/1/11/to_xls-plugin-export-to-excel-in-rails-the-easy-way). A better way might be for you to go to and from a CSV using [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) and get something that is usable. Here is one example: [Export to_csv from ActiveRecord](http://www.brynary.com/2007/4/28/export-activerecords-to-csv)

Comment: I have functions written to do what I want to do. I'm trying to focus on where I should put the code.